# KXStudio Repositories are compatible with Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: repository, ubuntu-studio, jack

I use Ubuntu Studio (http://ubuntustudio.org) but I added the KxStudio Repositories (https://kx.studio/Repositories) which are compatible with Ubuntu.

Some applications work and install without problems but for example, trying to install cadence removes a lot of ubuntu studio packages.

```
~$ sudo apt install cadence
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  carla-lv2 carla-vst libwine-development:i386 linux-headers-lowlatency
  linux-lowlatency python3-cffi python3-jack-client python3-pycparser
  ubuntustudio-lowlatency-settings ubuntustudio-performance-tweaks
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.

The following additional packages will be installed:
  claudia ladish
Suggested packages:
  gladish
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntustudio-controls ubuntustudio-default-settings ubuntustudio-desktop
  ubuntustudio-desktop-core ubuntustudio-installer ubuntustudio-menu
  ubuntustudio-menu-add
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cadence claudia ladish
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 7 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 641 kB of archives.
After this operation, 726 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

Looks like KXStudio is **not compatible** with Ubuntu Studio, but there are multiple applications I need that are only present in the kxStudio Repositories.

There is a way around it without compiling myself these aplications?

For reference, this is the output of apt update:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                            
Get:3 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release [6.598 B]                                                                    
Hit:4 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                        
Get:5 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]                                                       
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]                                                        
Get:8 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98,3 kB]                                                    
Hit:9 https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease                                                                        
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                              
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [103 kB]                                     
Get:12 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [143 kB]                                 
Get:13 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [532 B]                                
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bashtop-monitor/bashtop/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                   
Hit:15 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                            
Hit:16 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                            
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [18,6 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [31,6 kB]                   
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/libs/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/music/ubuntu bionic InRelease                
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/plugins/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/kxstudio/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pdesaulniers/wolf/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 615 kB in 5s (118 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: Please [edit your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1248056/edit) to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu Studio leader here. We cannot and do not support adding those repositories. We have a lot of people who come by and complain about broken systems by adding those repositories. Per our IRC chat bot:

> KXStudio is a software repository for Debian-based
> operating systems for audio production. It is not supported by Ubuntu
> or Ubuntu Studio, and using its repo is highly discouraged as it can
> overwrite system and user settings.

Since those repositories are not simple PPAs, they are not easy to remove and require an entire reinstallation to remove.

Considering the advantages of using Ubuntu Studio Controls over other methods of configuring Jack, and because Carla and many other plugins are included in the Ubuntu repositories, there is no real need to add KXStudio.

If you do need plugins from the KXStudio repositories that are not already part of Ubuntu, consider downloading the individual packages [directly from the website](https://kx.studio/Repositories:Plugins).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is strange that I am the first one to ask that on askubuntu.

Comment: Most of the time the question gets asked on IRC, so I'm glad I have something to link to when people ask. :)